# javax.enterprise.context not found Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: jsf, netbeans, glassfish, cdi, glassfish-4.1

I imported my old JSF project into Netbeans 8.0.2 and it keeps indicating that javax.enterprise.context is not found by underlining my imports with red lines.
I have done enough search and I found the netbeans team has resolved the issue. http://hg.netbeans.org/web-main/rev/3a3c32bf146f

The netbeans post suggests that changes should be done to the file glassfish.tooling/src/org/netbeans/modules/glassfish/tooling/server/config/ConfigBuilderProvider.java.

However, I have looked for the ConfigBuilderProvider.java and cannot find it any where. I don't seem to even see glassfish.tooling. I am using a mac. How do I get to this suggested file so that I can edit it?

Comment: I think your project missising cdi-api.jar.

add cdi-api.jar to the project by right-clicking on Libraries, selecting Add JAR/Folder, and selecting cdi-api.jar from the modules folder of glassfish installation.

Comment: "*`javax.enterprise.context` is not found by underlining my imports **with red lines**.*" You forgot to add the Java EE 7 API Library (I presume it is Java EE 7 because you are using GlassFish Server 4.1) to the compile-time class-path. Do it precisely. (This is not related to JSF/NetBeans).